# How do you assign function result to a var in Swft?

Tags: ios, swift, assign

I have a function but i don´t know assign the return to a var or let

```
func getCoords() -> String{
        var coords = "parameter"
        return coords

    }
```

i try this but not works

```
var result = getCoords()
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  What error message are you seeing?  Are you doing this in a playground or an app?  Is the function part of an object class or struct?

Answer (score 1):

I try both codes blow,both of them works with my playground.

```
    func getCoords() -> String{
        var coords = "parameter"
        return coords

    }
    var string = getCoords()
    string = "abc" + string//abcparameter
```

And

```
func getCoords() -> String{
    let coords = "parameter"
    return coords

}
var string = getCoords()
string = "abc" + string//abcparameter
```

Swift is a language pass by copy,so I think if you want a let or var.You can use this function like this.

```
let string = getCoords()//Get a let
var string = getCoords()//Get a var
```